# Could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org Please contact your server administrator

Tags: php, wordpress

I have uploaded basic wordpress through FTP server (WinSCP). Later I m trying to install plug ins - When I click Add new Button under Plugin Menu, I am getting below error.

> Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with
>   WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to
>   have problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress
>   could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please
>   contact your server administrator.) in
>   /---/----/---/wp-admin/includes/plugin-install.php on line 169

I gone thru many forums and tried below. 

1. CURL check - Its working fine

2. /etc/host entry for api.wordpress.org public IP

 3. 80 port open 
 everything seems to be fine in my case. still facing same issue. Anyone has idea on this? is this something related to SSL? If so please advice.

Comment: HTTPS connections are over port 443, check that too?

Comment: 80, 8080, 443 ports are open

Answer (score 2):

I tried to configure curl to use IPv4, by adding `curl_setopt($this->handle, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);` in wp-includes/Requests/Transport/cURL.php after the handle is created in the constructor. Both CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE and CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 are defined, so it had worked for me